# Is there a nontrivial but short example where the separable degree is strictly less than the degree of a field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, separable-spaces, separable-extension

I consider the following theorem:

Let $E\supset F\supset k$ be a tower. Then $$[E:k]_s=[E:F]_s\cdot [F:k]_s.$$ Furthermore if $E$ is finite over $k$ then $[E:k]_s$ is finite and $$[E:k]_s\leq [E:k].$$

> Now I am thinking about a nontrivial example where $$[E:k]_s<[E:k]$$ is strictly less.

But at the moment I can’t think about one. So I thought maybe one of you have an example in mind which could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Litterally any extension which is not separable. It has to happen in characteristic $p>0$, and the standard example is: $k=\mathbb{F}_p(X)$ and $E=\mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt[p]{X})$ (adjoining a $p$th root of $X$).

Comment: Ah okei but now if I would take $p=2$ then $k=\Bbb{F}_2(X)$ and $E=\Bbb{F}_2(\sqrt{X})$ but then if I understood it correctly $[E:k]_S=2$ and $[E:k]=3$ or is this wrong?

Comment: @aprozz In your example $[E:k]=2$. Think a little bit more about separability degree.

Comment: Sorry why $[E:k]=2$ in my example so I mean does $E$ not have dimension $3$ over $k$? 

And is $[E:k]_S=1$?

Comment: Seeing that $[E:k]_S=1$ is not completely trivial, but I think you should be able to figure out why taking a square root gives an extension of degree $2$.

Comment: @CaptainLama sorry could you give me a hint? Because I think that I need to count all extensions of the embedding $\sigma:k\rightarrow L$ to an embedding of $E$ in $L$. Where $L$ is an algebraically closed field but I don’t see how to count all possibilities